# Clarifying hiking lingo "return"

Tags: hiking, terminology

I am researching hikes in New Zealand.  What does it mean if it says "this hike is 5-6 hours return"?  Does it mean it will take 5-6 hours total or 5-6 hours each way?

Answer (score 14):

While this is not a hiking or even outdoors question - it is purely an English language question - I think it is common enough that it is worth popping an answer here:

In English, a duration followed by the word "return" means the time taken to travel there *and* back. i.e. including the return trip.

If the word "return" was not there, it would be the time taken to get to that destination, i.e. each way.

Comment: I agree with you on the return part, not sure I'd agree with the last bit. If I am reading about an out-n-back hike and it says 5-6 hours I'd often assume round trip. For example, All Trails (One of the most prevalent trail info services in the US), talks about out-n-back trails in terms of the full round trip length/time. It would depend a bit more on the context before you can determine if it's each way or total.

Comment: @noah in the case of the "out-n-back" hikes there may not be a definite "out" end, so the total time is what is important. An example might be a loop hike that goes  past several scenic bits in a large circle, but starts and ends in the same location. Rory Alsop is completely correct on the "return" meaning there-and-back, and usually indicates going out and returning along the same trail. A lack of return would be a single trip - as for a loop hike or time taken to reach a destination (i.e. one-way).

Comment: A loop hike is not really an "out-n-back" hike. It's then a loop hike which will be quoted as the time to complete the loop. My point was for an out-n-back hike if it says "the hike is 5-6 hours" that doesn't necessarily mean it's 5-6 hours each way. In fact it's usually the opposite. For ex: https://www.alltrails.com/trail/us/washington/hoh-river-trail-to-blue-glacier-trail?search=true. I think you'll have a hard time finding a website talking about an out-n-back hike with times for one direction (unless they list times for both directions when there are big differences due to elevation/etc)

Comment: For the record, this must be a regional thing—I’m a native English speaker (NYC) and I’ve never heard this phrasing before.

Comment: Normally if a time being given is for one direction only, at least on AllTrails, it will be listed as a 'point-to-point' hike rather than a 'loop' or 'out and back'.

Comment: @KRyan I'm a native speaker as well, and if I saw "The Fun Mountain Hike is 5-6 hours return", I would still be confused if that mean a round trip time, or just getting back takes 5-6 hours. I'd prefer it say "Fun Mountain Hike is a total of 5-6 hours, round trip" or something more explicit (to the point of being redundant even)

Comment: @KRyan Really? I am also an AmE speaker and this is strikes me as totally typical.

Comment: There does seem to be a slight preference for "round trip" in American English, while British English tends towards "Return". NZ is quite likely to be close to British in that sense. (@BruceWayne et al.)

Comment: ... The only time "return" would mean just the way back would be in explicit contrast to "outbound" or similar, and with a noun referring to sections. For example "the way out takes 2 hours but be sure to allow enough time for the return leg, which takes 4 because it's all uphill" (pretty unusual - it's rare to start at the top and walk down first)

Comment: Do Americans purchase 'return tickets' at train stations (e.g. 'a return [ticket] to Woking' is a ticket from my current location to Woking and back)? Because that's normal in the UK and one usage may have influenced the other.

Comment: I definitely wouldn't think of a "6 hour hike" (without return) as a 12 hour total hike (also there's absolutely no guarantee that the return way would be the same length as the way to the destination - most of my hikes it's more 2/3 to 1/3 if I had to guess), this seems to be a very regional thing. Can you link to any web site that really does this?

Comment: @KRyan - to be fair, native English is not what is spoken in either your location (USA) or mine (Scotland)

Comment: @dbmag9 I would call that a "roundtrip ticket". A return ticket sounds to me like it would just take you from Woking to the current location and not include the departure from the current location. Also, although I've spent some time at Amtrak stations, purchasing train tickets is not a relatable experience for most Americans. Amazing how much our cultures can differ!

Comment: +1  My comments:  1,  I would interpret "X hours return" as a round trip, as did Rory.  It would not make sense otherwise, or would have to be twisted and tortured into making sense and then only marginally.   2.  If a Q has even a smidgen of TGO-ness in it, better to ask it here.  In my experience, asking this question on English Language and Usage (ELL)  SE would produce a wave of utterly useless comments and answers;  there are very knowledgable outdoorsy people on ELL, but they are a minority;  on average ELL-ers know MUCH  less about the outdoors than we know about English.

Comment: AmE speaker here--while I would interpret this to mean the round trip time it's not a phrasing I ever recall hearing.  I have never seen trail time that isn't start to finish, but in some cases a separate start and finish location is specified.  The only time the halfway time is relevant is when for some reason you care about when you're at that point.  Things like summitting at sunrise, or high mountains where you want to avoid afternoon lightning.

Comment: It may be more of a Britishism, related to the phrase "return ticket to X" when buying a RR ticket to X,  meaning in US English:  "round trip to X".

Answer (score -6):

I'd go alternative way answering you question.

It doesn't mean anything practical for you. This information is **not trustworthy**.

Whatever source you're reading, the author should be **more specific** if he/she respects the reader, and not produces some click bait for monetizing on ads.

As a minimum, it should be clear from the context what is meant, so that you wouldn't need to ask. Second point, hours are not a reasonable unit to measure distance for hikes. Assuming the author has stated on the basis of own research it's about 5 hours, and not copied it from somewhere else, potentially making mistake, it's still 5 hours of some abstract *average hiker*, whatever it should be. A pensioner, a family with children, including picnicking break, or only moving time? A *5 hour* trail can take you 2 hours or 10 hours in your pace.

A reasonable resource should provide you with the **length and elevation gain** of the hike, so you could estimate the time you need based on your level of fitness. An information, how much could it take for a person with said fitness level is also valuable (heavy outdoor routes take more time for the same distance/elevation compared to paved trails). Without that information, it's a mere guessing.

Comment: The question wasn't "How long will the hike take" the question was "what does it meant this this estimate is for 'return'"

Comment: When establishing duration of the trails in NZ, they are walked by a range of groups of varying fitness and times are based on terrain, average walking speeds and proximity to tourist sites (i.e. people who don't necessarily know their ability to walk distance X)  etc.  Distance/elevation gain are not great estimators for many people in the outdoors because they don't correlate well - sure I can say on average 600 m altitude gain/hour or 5 km/h but that doesn't correlate with difficulty of terrain, state of the trail, experience etc, but saying that a trail should take you about Y hours....

Comment: ... a good estimate of "can I fit this into a day's walk?" and "can I walk this long?" and might put off those who might not be able to - the inexperienced, who are also less likely to take safety gear, more likely to get injured etc. Check out [this track](https://www.doc.govt.nz/parks-and-recreation/places-to-go/otago/places/mount-aspiring-national-park/things-to-do/tracks/gillespie-pass-circuit/) Find Young Hut and Siberia Hut, look at the distance and terrain between in the map - it looks simple right? It's a 6-8 h walk over only 12 km! This is a very popular trail, easily underestimated.